# centering div with css

Tags: html, css, alignment

This is the snippet from my css file

```
#centered{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
#table{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 900;
    background-color: #5E9DC8;
}
```

This is the html section that I'm trying to use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bicycle Store Database</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <h1>ACME BICYCLE SHOP</h1>
    <h2>GET IN GEAR!</h2>

    <div id="centered">
    <table id="table" border="0" cellpadding="10"> 
        <tr>
            <td><a href="search_inv.php" class="navTest">Go Shopping!</a><br/><br/>
            <a href="search_service.html" class="navTest">Check a Service Ticket</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>

    <p><br/><a href="index.html">HOME</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the result:

[image: div is not centered]

Everything I've read indicates that I've done this correctly, but it's off centered in all my browsers. Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't have any tabular data there, you shouldn't be using a table element.

Comment: It is considered a bad practise to use `table` to style the page; use it when it's required to display table data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are using table for that? any specific reason? Can't you simply do it like this?

```
<div class="center">
  <a href="#">Go Shopping</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>

.center {
   margin: auto;
   /* Other styles goes here, width height background etc */
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, this one kind of sums it all up. I got rid of the table and fixed my css and everything is dialed.

Answer (score 1):

you are centering `#centered` but not the table in it. 
add `margin:0 auto;` to `#table`.

Answer (score 0):

The div is centred in the page.

The table is left aligned in the div.

Add `table { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }` to centre the table in the div.